Calculating Number of Days Finished Goods Spend in Warehouse with No Next Destination
I'm working on a Power BI project where I need to calculate the number of days finished goods spend in a warehouse with no next destination. Here's the scenario:
1- I have a dataset containing information about warehouse movements, including the dates when parts enter and exit each warehouse.
2-The finished goods move through several warehouses, including ones that start with "WIP" (Work In Progress), until they reach a final warehouse, let's call it "Warehouse 4", where they remain until being sold.
3-Unlike with raw materials (where I can calculate the number of days spent waiting by looking at the next warehouse movement), there is no next warehouse after the finished goods leave the WIP warehouses. They directly enter "Warehouse 4".
Given this scenario, I need to calculate the number of days finished goods spend in "Warehouse 4" before being sold. How can I achieve this in Power BI, considering I'm working with the value of part numbers and need to track the evolution of this metric over time?
I'm familiar with using measures and DAX calculations in Power BI, but I'm unsure how to handle this specific scenario where there is no next warehouse movement to reference.
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
